# How to make profile as link to share

Tags: flutter, hyperlink, share, flutter-web, user-profile

I am going to create a chat application using flutter with the firebase database, I want to add a profile sharing feature that opens a specific profile by its profile link, e.g. In Telegram, we have our own profile id and we can share it as https://t.me/username, just of one click it opens with telegram app with that specific user profile. Then how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Firebase Dynamic Links

[Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) is the service that does what you're describing. The documentation states the following:

> You create a Dynamic Link either by using the Firebase console, using
> a REST API, iOS or Android Builder API, or by forming a URL by adding
> Dynamic Link parameters to a domain specific to your app. These
> parameters specify the links you want to open, depending on the user's
> platform and whether your app is installed.

### Setup

1. First, you will need to enable it for your Firebase project through your [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/durablelinks).
2. Then, you will include its official package for Flutter called [firebase_dynamic_links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) in your app.
3. You can create Dynamic Links programmatically with your app or maybe Cloud Functions or by using the Firebase console.
4. Use the firebase_dynamic_links package to check if a Dynamic Link was passed to it when your app opens.
5. You can view the analytics data to track the performance of your Dynamic Links in the Firebase console.